# ImageMapper Not working due to JQUERY or HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was following this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nYkAG/396/ it works perfectly well.

Code Below:

```
<img id="beatles" src="http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/examples/images/beatles_basic.jpg" 
style="width:400px;height:240px;" usemap="#beatles-map">
  <map name="beatles-map">
    <area shape="rect" data-name="paul,all" coords="36,46,121,131" href="#" />
    <area shape="rect" data-name="ringo,all" coords="113,76,198,161" href="#" />
    <area shape="rect" data-name="john,all" coords="192,50,277,135" href="#" />
    <area shape="rect" data-name="george,all" coords="262,60,347,145" href="#" />
  </map>

<div id="beatles-caption" style="clear:both;border: 1px solid black; width: 400px; padding: 6px; display:none;">
 <div id="beatles-caption-header" style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 12px;"></div>
 <div id="beatles-caption-text"></div>
</div>​
```

However, why is this not wokring for this index1.html (test)?

http://nina-naustdal.com/index1.html

Thanks for your assistance

Comment: if you look at the jsfiddle listed above, when you hover over the image, the `<area>` tag allows a tooltip to appear at the bottom. However, when recreating such an event on the index1.html does not work, even tho i am using the same code.

Comment: The fiddle includes JavaScript, your code does not.

Comment: Had same problem and re-asked the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133314/imagemapper-beatles-demo-wont-run-outside-jsfiddle).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your page, I do not see the JavaScript that accompanies the jsFiddle.

I see a plugin called 'imagemapster', but it does not seem to relate to the code in your fiddle example.

Further investigation confirms that you have not included the relevant JavaScript from the JS window in the fiddle.

You need to add this script:

```
// javascript
// Set up some options objects: 'single_opts' for when a single area is selected, which will show just a border
// 'all_opts' for when all are highlighted, to use a different effect - shaded white with a white border
// 'initial_opts' for general options that apply to the whole mapster. 'initial_opts' also includes callbacks
// onMouseover and onMouseout, which are fired when an area is entered or left. We will use these to show or
// remove the captions, and also set a flag to let the other code know if we're currently in an area.
var inArea, map = $('#beatles'),
    captions = {
        paul: ["Paul McCartney - Bass Guitar and Vocals",
                                                                                            "Paul McCartney's song, Yesterday, recently voted the most popular song "
                                                                                              + "of the century by a BBC poll, was initially composed without lyrics. "
                                                                                              + "Paul used the working title 'scrambled eggs' before coming up with the final words."],
        ringo: ["Ringo Starr - Drums",
                                                                                          "Dear Prudence was written by John and Paul about Mia Farrow's sister, Prudence, "
                                                                                            + "when she wouldn't come out and play with Mia and the Beatles at a religious retreat "
                                                                                            + "in India."],
        john: ["John Lennon - Guitar and Vocals",
                                                                                          "In 1962, The Beatles won the Mersyside Newspaper's biggest band in Liverpool "
                                                                                            + "contest principally because they called in posing as different people and voted "
                                                                                            + "for themselves numerous times."],
        george: ["George Harrison - Lead Guitar and Vocals",
                                                                                         "The Beatles' last public concert was held in San Francisco's Candlestick "
                                                                                            + "Park on August 29, 1966."]
    },
    single_opts = {
        fillColor: '000000',
        fillOpacity: 0,
        stroke: true,
        strokeColor: 'ff0000',
        strokeWidth: 2
    },
    all_opts = {
        fillColor: 'ffffff',
        fillOpacity: 0.6,
        stroke: true,
        strokeWidth: 2,
        strokeColor: 'ffffff'
    },
    initial_opts = {
        mapKey: 'data-name',
        isSelectable: false,
        onMouseover: function(data) {
            inArea = true;
            $('#beatles-caption-header').text(captions[data.key][0]);
            $('#beatles-caption-text').text(captions[data.key][1]);
            $('#beatles-caption').show();
        },
        onMouseout: function(data) {
            inArea = false;
            $('#beatles-caption').hide();
        }
    };
opts = $.extend({}, all_opts, initial_opts, single_opts);


// Bind to the image 'mouseover' and 'mouseout' events to activate or deactivate ALL the areas, like the
// original demo. Check whether an area has been activated with "inArea" - IE<9 fires "onmouseover"
// again for the image when entering an area, so all areas would stay highlighted when entering
// a specific area in those browsers otherwise. It makes no difference for other browsers.
map.mapster('unbind').mapster(opts).bind('mouseover', function() {
    if (!inArea) {
        map.mapster('set_options', all_opts).mapster('set', true, 'all').mapster('set_options', single_opts);
    }
}).bind('mouseout', function() {
    if (!inArea) {
        map.mapster('set', false, 'all');
    }
});
```

Comment: The imagemapster is in the resources page and is currently on the index1.html, any other suggestions on why this is happening?

Comment: Yes, the relevant JavaScript from the jsFiddle you referenced is NOT on the page. You have a reference to the plugin, but not the code that runs it. (updated answer to include relevant code)

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply. I have added that code onto the website again. However, nothing. Any other suggestions?